# Kafka Streams Change internal topic name

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using kafka-streams:2.7.0 in my Springboot application. I have to join two KStreams and change internal topic name.

```
KStream messageToRetry=messageStream.join(
                            keyToRetryStream,
                            documentJoiner,
                            JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(30)),
                            StreamJoined.with(Serdes.String(), docSerde, docSerde).withStoreName("test123"))
```

Internal topics follows the naming convention:`${applicationId}-<storename>-changelog`
So my Auto-generated topic name is :

```
kafka-streams-dev-KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000004-store-changelog
```

I'm using `StreamJoined.withStoreName(„test123”)` to change store name and I'm expected sth like:
`kafka-streams-dev-test123-store-changelog`

But I've got:

```
kafka-streams-dev-test123-other-join-store-changelog
```

Is `StreamJoined.withStoreName()` right method to change the store name? Is there any documentation which explain when `other-join` suffix is added?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in javaDoc: https://kafka.apache.org/27/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/StreamJoined.html#withStoreName-java.lang.String-

The name for the stores will be ${applicationId}--**this-join** and ${applicationId}--**other-join**.

However the name of the store depends on which join we are using (inner-other-join/outer-other-join).